# Discord Bot C# (D#) trouble moving the ctx.Member into a newly created voice channel

Tags: c#, bots, discord

[Command("fights")]

[RequireRoles(RoleCheckMode.All, "Novice")]

```
    public async Task Queue(CommandContext ctx)
    {

        var fighterName = ctx.Message.Author.Id;
        var server = ctx.Guild;
        var name = ctx.Member.Username;     
        int? userLimit = 2;                 
        var member = ctx.Member;

        var fightCategory = await server.CreateChannelAsync($"{name} Vs ", ChannelType.Category);   // This area just creates the Category, 
        await server.CreateChannelAsync("Bets and Feed", ChannelType.Text, fightCategory);          // Text, and Voice channels and sorts them   
        var fightVoiceChannel = await server.CreateChannelAsync($"For", ChannelType.Voice, fightCategory, default, null, userLimit); 


        { 
            await ctx.Channel.SendMessageAsync($"{member} has being intiated into the fight and the channel {name} Vs has been made to do your betting");

            await ctx.Channel.SendMessageAsync($"{fightVoiceChannel} has been created and you will be placed shortly"); 

            await member.PlaceInAsync(fightVoiceChannel);       // To put a person into a voice channel.
                                                                // These are both two different ways
            await fightVoiceChannel.PlaceMemberAsync(member);   // I still can't get them to work though
        }

    }
```

I'm very new to all of this but I honestly can't see why the last two lines will not do what it looks like they should. I can compile the program and run it. The Category, Text Channel, and Voice Channel get created and the messages go out but the last two lines will not do anything. I only have them both there because I was testing different ways of doing it. I have tried with taking each one out and have only one of them there

Comment: What is “D#”, and where does it manifest in the question?

Comment: await member.PlaceInAsync(fightChannel)

D# is an API used to make coding discord bots easier I guess? I'm fairly new to all of this. definitely new to C#.

Comment: ctx.Member is a 'DiscordMember CommandContext.Member' which is the member that set the command off. 
I assign that to a var 'member'.

PlaceInAsync(DiscordChannel) places you in a discord channel that you assign

fightVoiceChannel = server.CreateChannelAsync($"For", ChannelType.Voice, fightCategory, default, null, userLimit); <-- which gets created fine with the userLimit of 2 and everything.

That is when I call it in await member.PlaceInAsync(fightVoiceChannel);

So it should do await person that sent the message and send them to this voice channel that you just created.

Comment: The 2nd version I have is await fightVoiceChannel.PlaceMemberAsync(member); which is the same as my above comment but backwards. It says await channel I just created and place this var member (person who executed command) in it.

Answer (score 0):

so apparently Discord will not allow you to be pulled into a Voice Channel unless you are already in a voice channel. This was a rule I was unaware of. Thanks for trying to help. I wanted to leave this update in case anyone else has this problem.

The code works. It will pull me into the designated channel as long as I am already in one!

Thanks for trying!

Comment: You can accept your own answer so people now this issue is resolved.